# PySide2 use QProgressBar as signal argument

Tags: python, signals-slots, pyside2

I am trying to solve a problem with PySide2, QThread and the Signal/Slot mechanism.

What I want to achieve is updating a specific progressbar which is passed as reference via signal/slot mechanism.

The problem is the call of `self.gui_connection.signal_progress_value.emit(lambda: self.progressbar, value)` in my ProgressBarThread class.

The program stops after emitting the signal with a QProgressBar and an int value as arguments and causes a Seg Fault. If I just pass an int value to the signal and call emit in my ProgressBarThread everything is working fine.

Is it just not possible to pass an Object via Signal/Slot mechanism?

(Reduced) Code Samples:

GUISignal.py

```
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, Signal
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QProgressBar

class GUISignal(QObject):
    signal_progress_value = Signal(QProgressBar, int)
```

main.py

```
# File: main.py
import sys
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton
from PySide2.QtCore import QFile
from config.configManager import ConfigManager
from layout.srcConfigLayout import SrcConfigLayout
from layout.ingestLayout import IngestLayout

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    ui_file = QFile("main_window.ui")
    ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)

    loader = QUiLoader()
    window = loader.load(ui_file)
    ui_file.close()
    window.show()

    src_config_layout = SrcConfigLayout(window)
    ingestLayout = IngestLayout(window)
    src_config_layout.load_config()
    ingestLayout.load_config()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

ingestLayout.py

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QPushButton, QProgressBar
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, Slot

from util.ingestManager import IngestManager
from config.configManager import ConfigManager
from util.progressBarThread import ProgressBarThread

from functools import partial

class IngestLayout(QObject):    

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent

    def handleIngestClicked(self, srcpath, destpath, progressbar):
        ingestManager = IngestManager()
        ingestManager.copy_to_destination(self, srcpath, destpath)
        progressThread = ProgressBarThread(srcpath, destpath, progressbar, self.parent)
        progressThread.gui_connection.signal_progress_value.connect(self.updateProgressbar)
        progressThread.start()

    @Slot(QProgressBar, int)
    def updateProgressbar(self, progressbar: QProgressBar, value: int):
        pass
        # progressbar.setValue(value)
```

progressBarThread.py

```
from PySide2.QtCore import QThread
import os
import threading
import time
from signals.GUISignal import GUISignal

class ProgressBarThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, srcpath, destpath, progressbar, parent):
        super(ProgressBarThread, self).__init__(parent)
        self.gui_connection = GUISignal()
        self.srcpath = srcpath
        self.destpath = destpath
        self.src_size = self.size(srcpath)
        self.progressbar = progressbar

    def run(self):
        self.periodically_compare_folder_size()

    def periodically_compare_folder_size(self):
        dest_size = self.size(self.destpath)
        while self.src_size > dest_size:
            value = self.calc_progress(self.src_size, dest_size)
            self.gui_connection.signal_progress_value.emit(lambda: self.progressbar, value)
            dest_size = self.size(self.destpath)
            time.sleep(2)
        else:
            self.gui_connection.signal_progress_value.emit(lambda: self.progressbar, 100)
            print(100)
            return

    def size(self, path, *, follow_symlinks=False):
        try:
            with os.scandir(path) as it:
                return sum(self.size(entry, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks) for entry in it)
        except NotADirectoryError:
            return os.stat(path, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks).st_size

    def calc_progress(self, src_size, dest_size):
        return dest_size / src_size * 100
```

The problem is that the program stops after emitting the signal with a QProgressBar and a value as arguments and causes a Seg Fault. If I just pass an int value to the signal and call emit in my ProgressBarThread everything is working fine.

Is it just not possible to pass Object via Signal/Slot mechanism?

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Where do you call handleIngestClicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not necessary for the signal to send as QProgressBar dates, in addition to the GUI is not thread-safe, on the other hand it is not necessary to use a lambda.

Considering the above, the solution is:

```
class GUISignal(QObject):
    signal_progress_value = Signal(int)
```

```
class ProgressBarThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, srcpath, destpath, parent):
        super(ProgressBarThread, self).__init__(parent)
        self.gui_connection = GUISignal()
        self.srcpath = srcpath
        self.destpath = destpath
        self.src_size = self.size(srcpath)

    def run(self):
        self.periodically_compare_folder_size()

    def periodically_compare_folder_size(self):
        dest_size = self.size(self.destpath)
        while self.src_size > dest_size:
            value = self.calc_progress(self.src_size, dest_size)
            self.gui_connection.signal_progress_value.emit(value)
            dest_size = self.size(self.destpath)
            time.sleep(2)
        else:
            self.gui_connection.signal_progress_value.emit(100)
            print(100)
            return
    # ...
```

```
def handleIngestClicked(self, srcpath, destpath, progressbar):
    ingestManager = IngestManager()
    ingestManager.copy_to_destination(self, srcpath, destpath)
    progressThread = ProgressBarThread(srcpath, destpath, self.parent)
    progressThread.gui_connection.signal_progress_value.connect(progressbar.setValue)
    progressThread.start()
```

**Update:**

In the previous part of my answer I separate the GUI from the business logic as this will have a more scalable SW. But the OP seems to not want that so the simple solution is not to use the lambda method since it is unnecessary:

```py
self.gui_connection.signal_progress_value.emit(self.progressbar, value)
```

```py
self.gui_connection.signal_progress_value.emit(self.progressbar, 100)
```

Comment: Thanks I know what you mean. I will try this soon. But there is the overall question if it's possible to pass objects (for example an QProgressBar or any other object) to signal/slots. It seems like it is not intended. The Signal/Slot docs from PySide2 only describe using strings or ints to pass to slots..

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:
The problem was the lambda function in the emit function inside the QThread class. It seems like the object was not passed by the lambda function. Just using `.emit(self,progressbar, 100) is working.`

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I indicated in my update